# How to calculate position of circle inside another circle?

Tags: math, geometry, degrees

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the x,y point of a circle as it rotates inside of another circle as shown in the image.

Given the angle what is the math formula needed to calculate the x,y value of the inner circle?

---

Solution in javascript:

```
function innerX(angle) {
    var rad = toRadians(angleOffset(angle));

    var sx = cx + (R-r)*Math.cos(rad);

    return sx;
}

function innerY(angle) {
    var rad = toRadians(angleOffset(angle));

    var sy = cy + (R-r)*Math.sin(rad);

    return sy;
}

function topLeft(angle) {
    var sx = innerX(angle);
    var sy = innerY(angle);
  
    var tl = [sx - r, sy -r];

    return tl;
}
```

See full code:
https://jsfiddle.net/axmjh45u/2/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about math, not about programming

Comment: Stackoverflow has a math tag with many questions related. Why wouldn't we post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With large circle center `cx, cy`, large radius `R`, small radius `r`, we can see that small circle center is

```
sx = cx + (R-r)*cos(angle - Pi/2)
sy = cy + (R-r)*sin(angle - Pi/2)
```

So circumscribed rectangle coordinates are

```
top = sx - r
left = sy - r
and similar for right, bottom
```

I added `-Pi/2` summand because  your zero angle corresponds to `-Pi/2 (270 or -90 degrees)` direction

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm a little confused on the angle part. The angle would be between 0 and 360. Say for the second example would it be sin(60 - Pi/2)?

Comment: Zero angle corresponds to OX axis direction (usually). Check for your coordinate system. If you work in degrees (in most languages sin and cos require radians), subtract 90 degrees. So for 60 degrees case: `sin(60 - 90)`  (if your math library sin takes degree argument)

Comment: @user3325492 Have you got desired result? P.S. It is worth to edit your question adding a bit of code to make question more suitable for purists :)

Comment: I'm still trying to work through it. Its taking me some time since math is not my first language :). I will try to provide the final code solution if i can get it working properly.

Comment: Seems to work well. Here is my code in javascript if anyone is interested. https://jsfiddle.net/axmjh45u/2/